# Is there an advantage to using parse_str for optional function parameters vs an array?

Tags: php, optional-parameters, function-parameter

I  happened to be making some changes to a WordPress blog and noticed that they use `parse_str` (http://php.net/parse_str) for parsing and setting their optional parameters to a function.

I'm wondering if there is an advantage to this over sending an array?

Examples:

With array:

```
$blahOptions = array(
    'option_1' => true,
);
BlahArray($blahOptions);
function BlahArray($options = array()) {
    $defaults = array(
        'option_1' => false,
        'option_2' => 'blah',
    );
    // this would probably be in a function to be used everywhere
    foreach ($defaults as $defaultOption => $defaultValue) {
        if (!isset($options[$defaultOption])) $options[$defaultOption] = $defaultValue;
    }
}
```

With `parse_str`:

```
$blahOptions = 'option_1=1';
BlahString($blahOptions);
function BlahString($options = '') {
    $defaults = array(
        'option_1' => false,
        'option_2' => 'blah',
    );
    parse_str($options, $defaults);
    $options = $defaults;
}
```

Comment: Just a side-note, why not use array_merge instead of the foreach? $options = array_merge($defaults, $options);

Comment: In the above example, array_merge would work, but unfortunately, array_merge and array_merge_recursive do funky things with nested arrays and numeric keys. array_merge: with numeric keys it won't replace the keys, but instead add and reorder the keys. array_merge_recursive: it will merge nested arrays, which most often, you don't want when sending options to a function. It also does the same things with numeric keys as array_merge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  That seems like a ridiculous way to pass functional parameter arguments.  I could understand it if you needed to recreate $_GET or $_POST variables or something along those lines, but for parameters to a function?  That's code smell right there.

They should be using an array, and then utilizing [extract()](http://www.php.net/extract) instead.  I've worked with Wordpress before, and my advice is to keep the code at arm's length.  It is not an example of model programming.

Comment: I can see the advantage of passing GET and POST directly in, but that'd be quite scary.

Answer (score 2):

No. There are more disadvantages than advantages.

When you’re using a single string, you just can pass string values. With an array you can use every PHP data type and every element’s value type is independently of each other.

Comment: You can still pass arrays, just use the format: name[key1]=val&name[key2]=val But otherwise, things like resources would be impossible.

Comment: But you cannot distinguish between data types unless you are using some special format.

Answer (score 1):

With parse_str, you can potentially drop in the query string from the URL, and the function will work.  If you use an array, and you want to use the query string, you'll have to enumerate everything into an array before calling the function.

I'm not totally convinced it's the best way to go, but I see how it can add a bit of flexibility.